# Alternative to ffmpeg for dynamically creating video thumbnails

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

The server hosting my website doesn't have ffmpeg and I am not allowed to install any additional extensions. Is there any other way I can make video thumbnails dynamically? Perhaps some kind of web service, where I pass the video file and as a result I get a picture file. I'm using php, by the way.

Comment: Yet another alternative is to create thumbnails on the client. Can you describe what is the way of creating and uploading videos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using external service won't be feasible, since even if you find one, you'll have to PUSH whole video to it and get the thumbnail results back.

I recommend you that you host your videos somewhere where you can install ffmpeg or some other utility that will produce your thumbnails, then access (reference) whole deal from your original server location.

EDIT:

Yet another alternative is to create thumbnails on the client.  Can you describe what is the way of creating and uploading videos?

Comment: Well, I might get around this problem using flash. I know how to make a thumbnail with videodisplay and then upload it to the server. The only drawback is that every time a user uplaods a video, I have to force them to choose a thumbnail. But if there is no other way...

Comment: Flash would be your best option... I would be glad if there is some kind of 'out-of-the-box' solution, but...

Answer (score 1):

Do it in the browser with HTML5's video tag and canvas:
https://gist.github.com/adamjimenez/5917897

Comment: Wouldn't this approach require the client to download the fullsize copy of the video? Since we're talking about thumbnails, it seems likely that there would be many video elements on any page.

Comment: Yes, the admin user can run the page in their browser to generate all the thumbnails. This can be done as a one-off operation or as part of an admin system.

Answer (score 0):

See here:

http://www.facelooktube.info/wb/?category_name=svtm1

This software is created for creating thumbnails from video files. It can be used for video portals on low-cost servers without ffmpeg or you can use it if you need to replace auto created thumbnail of uploaded video.

Comment: Can you include the name of the software and an example of how to use and/or how it works?

Answer (score -1):

Sothink's [Video Encoder Engine](http://www.sothinkmedia.com/flash-video-encoder-command-line/) may do what you expect. It said on the product page that can auto create meaningful thumbnail image and Add PNG watermark image as logo. Hope it helps.

Comment: This is very unlikely to be helpful as the question states that the user is unable to install software on the server.