# Is there any way to create a video thumbnail through PHP without ffmpeg?

Tags: php, video, thumbnails

Is there any way to create a video thumbnail through PHP **without** ffmpeg?

My hosting server doesn't provide ffmpeg, so I need an alternative way (open source and free).

I have searched everywhere but no luck so far.

Comment: possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081045/alternative-to-ffmpeg-for-dynamically-creating-video-

Comment: I have answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179522/create-thumbnail-from-video-without-ffmpeg-in-php/21268642#21268642

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can implement the decoding algorithm for the video in question yourself, in PHP. Chances are you do not want to do that. So you will have to use a library that already implemented these algorithms. [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is one of those libraries, [libav](http://libav.org/) would be another. You could write a PECL to interface either library to run certain functions (like extracting a frame) from within your PHP process.

But I honestly do not see why you would want to go through either of that. So the question boils down to **»why are you asking for a solution without ffmpeg?«**

*Is it not available on your server?* Ask your IT-Support if they can make it available to you. If they can't, consider switching providers.

Comment: Thanx a lot for your answer. I asked the hosting provider but they don't support it. Time to change I guess. Cheers and thanx again!