# Generating a thumbnail from an uploaded video stream?

Tags: c#, video, azure, ffmpeg

I am building a page for people to upload video files using C#, .NET MVC and Azure. These files are stored in Azure blob storage. I want to generate a thumbnail during upload. But the only solutions I found to generate thumbnails from video are using ffmpeg wrappers and these can only operate on actual files on the filesystem, not streams. Is there a way to capture a still from a stream? The video is only available as either a blob or a stream, I really can't store local copies for making thumbnails. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do it using HTML5, read the local file, generate the thumbnails, and upload them to the server, please check this article, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/. The javascript to generate thumbnail would have to be done locally or on the server using ffmpeg.

The relevant bit would be the file slice feature,

```
<style>
  #byte_content {
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #byte_range { margin-top: 5px; }
</style>

<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button data-startbyte="0" data-endbyte="4">1-5</button>
  <button data-startbyte="5" data-endbyte="14">6-15</button>
  <button data-startbyte="6" data-endbyte="7">7-8</button>
  <button>entire file</button>
</span>
<div id="byte_range"></div>
<div id="byte_content"></div>

<script>
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {
    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }

    var file = files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;

    var reader = new FileReader();

    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
        if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
            document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
        document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = 
            ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
             ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('');
        }
    };

    **var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);**
}

document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
        var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
        var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
        readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
}, false);
</script>
```

Another approach would be to use HTML5 canvas element to play the video and generate thumbnail as described here, [Create thumbnail from video without ffmpeg in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179522/create-thumbnail-from-video-without-ffmpeg-in-php)

Comment: That's a nice suggestion, thanks. Not dure if I can get this to work but it's worth trying.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve your goal (get thumbnail) with [VideoConverter FFMpeg wrapper](http://www.nrecosite.com/video_converter_net.aspx) - it supports live streams conversions using stdin/stdout pipes. General idea is converting stream to raw video (actually bitmap frames stream) and use appropriate frame as thumbnail.

Note that this is possible ONLY for "streamable" video formats (for instance, MP4 cannot be processed as live stream).

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question as I created a working solution based on this article by Kashif Imran 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/496864/Getting-Thumbnail-from-Video-using-MediaPlayer-Cla

Code below will yield a new thumbnail every 800ms.

```
    public static IEnumerable<ThumbnailData> GenerateThumbnails(string mediaFile, int amount, System.Drawing.Size? imagesize)
    {
        System.Drawing.Size size = imagesize ?? new System.Drawing.Size(120, 80);
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer { Volume = 0, ScrubbingEnabled = true };

        player.Open(new Uri(mediaFile));
        player.Pause();
        //We need to give MediaPlayer some time to load. 
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(800);
        var totalduration = player.NaturalDuration;
        if (!totalduration.HasTimeSpan)
        {
            yield break;
        }
        double avglen = totalduration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds / (amount + 1d);
        for (int frameId = 0; frameId < amount; frameId++)
        {
            var timespan = avglen * (frameId + 1);
            var offset = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timespan);
            player.Position = offset;
            player.Play();
            player.Pause();

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(400);

            RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(size.Width, size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
            {
                dc.DrawVideo(player, new Rect(0, 0, size.Width, size.Height));
            }
            rtb.Render(dv);
            Duration duration = player.NaturalDuration;

            BitmapFrame frame = BitmapFrame.Create(rtb).GetCurrentValueAsFrozen() as BitmapFrame;
            BitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(frame as BitmapFrame);
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            encoder.Save(memoryStream);
            //Here we have the thumbnail in the MemoryStream!
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var thumbnail = new Bitmap(memoryStream);

            yield return new ThumbnailData { Offset = offset, Image = thumbnail };
        }

        player.Close();
    }
```