# Creating thumbnail from uploaded videos in php

Tags: javascript, html

Edit from original questions. So I've had a look at the link to the question suggested in the comments but I'm not sure how to apply it to my code. So for uploading a video I do it like so:

```
    <form action='videoUpload.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

<input type='hidden' name='id' value=''>

```
<p><label>Title</label><br />

<input type='text' name='videoTitle' required value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['videoTitle'];}?>'></p>

<p><label>Video</label><br />

<input type="file" name='video' id="video" required value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['video'];}?>'></p>

<input type="hidden" name='videoDuration' id="videoDuration" required value='<?php if(isset($error)){ echo $_POST['videoDuration'];}?>'></p>

        <div id="duration" name="duration">Please choose a video</div>
          <script src="duration.js"></script>
            <script src="thumbnail.js"></script>

<p><input type='submit' name='submit' id='submit' value='Submit'></p>
```

Edit:
So I'm hoping this is the final edit now, I have now gone about this another way, I am now able to get a thumbnail with the following js (of course I'm open to suggestions to improve this) :

```
const thumbnail = document.querySelector('.video');
    thumbnail.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
for (let i= document.images.length; i-->0;)
    document.images[i].parentNode.removeChild(document.images[i]);
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      let fileReader = new FileReader();
      if (file.type.match('image')) {
        fileReader.onload = function() {
          let img = document.createElement('img');
          img.src = fileReader.result;
          document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(img);
        };
        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      } else {
        fileReader.onload = function() {
          let blob = new Blob([fileReader.result], {type: file.type});
          let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          let video = document.createElement('video');
          let timeupdate = function() {
            if (snapImage()) {
              video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
              video.pause();
            }
          };
          video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
            if (snapImage()) {
              video.removeEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
            }
          });
          let snapImage = function() {
            let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
            canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
            canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            let image = canvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(image);
            let success = image.length > 100000;
            if (success) {
              let img = document.createElement('img');
              img.src = image;
              document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(img);
              URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            }
            return success;
          };
          video.addEventListener('timeupdate', timeupdate);
          video.preload = 'metadata';
          video.src = url;
          // Load video in Safari / IE11
          video.muted = true;
          video.playsInline = true;
          video.play();
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }
    });
```

This script allows me to get an image from the video which I can use as a thumbnail, however what would be the best way so I can pass the image through the form so I can add it to the database with the rest of the data?

I had thought about adding another input type="file" however after doing a bit of research I see due to security issues you can't use js to manipulate the value of this type of input? So what would be a good way for me to pass the image into the form?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create thumbnail from video without ffmpeg in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179522/create-thumbnail-from-video-without-ffmpeg-in-php)

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what's going on there, so would I need to add the video to a canvas once uploaded and then from there I can use the code they have there to create a thumbnail image?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the code in this [github gist](https://gist.github.com/adamjimenez/5917897) that uses html5 video and canvas tag.

ffmpeg can be a bit tricky and difficult to implement. Try this, it's a good option

Comment: Thank you!, I'll give this a go

Comment: Hi, I've just got round to trying to implement this but still having issues, would you be able to have a look at my updated question and see if you can tell where I'm going wrong please? Thanks